# Reverse the mouse scroll direction in google charts

Tags: google-visualization

I am using Line chart in my app. I need the mouse scroll should be like we have for google maps(scroll up - zoom in & scroll down - zoom out). The default behavior of google charts of quite opposite. How to change the default behavior? Can anyone help me?

Comment: check [options](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#configuration-options) for --> `explorer`

Comment: You can set `explorer.zoomDelta` to a number less than 1, but it seems buggy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In google charts, we don't have that customization.